# Remove same columns from left_join

Tags: r, dplyr

I'd like to merge two data frames by `id`, but they both have 2 of the same columns; therefore, when I merge i get new `.x` and `.y` columns.  How can I merge these two data frames with `left_join()` and remove the extra columns currently in my code that are the same (`element.x, day.x, element.y, and day.y) and keep a single column.

Code:

```
# Sample data
df1 <- data.frame(id = seq(1,5), value1 = rnorm(5), element = "TEST1", day = 15) 
df2 <- data.frame(id = seq(1,5), value2 = rnorm(5), element = "TEST1", day = 15) 

# Merge
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "id")

# Output
  id      value1 element.x day.x     value2 element.y day.y
1  1 -0.69700149     TEST1    15  1.4324220     TEST1    15
2  2 -0.25514949     TEST1    15  0.7281354     TEST1    15
3  3  0.09206902     TEST1    15  0.8148839     TEST1    15
4  4  2.51799237     TEST1    15  1.3919671     TEST1    15
5  5 -0.77049050     TEST1    15 -0.2707201     TEST1    15
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just drop everything you don't want from `df2` - in this case the `id` and `value2` columns:

```
left_join(df1, select(df2, c(id,value2)), by = "id")

#  id     value1 element day     value2
#1  1  1.2276303   TEST1  15 -0.1389861
#2  2 -0.8017795   TEST1  15 -0.5973131
#3  3 -1.0803926   TEST1  15 -2.1839668
#4  4 -0.1575344   TEST1  15  0.2408173
#5  5 -1.0717600   TEST1  15 -0.2593554
```

Beware that not all these answers are equivalent, and ask what it is you need as a result. E.g.:

```
df1 <- data.frame(id=1:3,day=2:4,element=3:5,value1=100:102)
df2 <- data.frame(id=1:3,day=3:5,element=4:6,value2=200:202)
df1

#  id day element value1
#1  1   2       3    100
#2  2   3       4    101
#3  3   4       5    102

df2
#  id day element value2
#1  1   3       4    200
#2  2   4       5    201
#3  3   5       6    202

left_join(df1, df2)
#Joining by: c("id", "day", "element")
#  id day element value1 value2
#1  1   2       3    100     NA
#2  2   3       4    101     NA
#3  3   4       5    102     NA

left_join(df1, select(df2, c(id,value2)), by = "id")
#  id day element value1 value2
#1  1   2       3    100    200
#2  2   3       4    101    201
#3  3   4       5    102    202
```

Comment: This is helps because I have a lot of variables in the original data set I'm working with are the same, but only need to merge by 3.  THanks!

Answer (score 10):

You only need:

```
df <- left_join(df1, df2)
```

> by = NULL, the default, `join` will do a natural join, using all variables with
>   common names across the two tables. A message lists the variables so
>   that you can check they're right

Output:

```
Joining by: c("id", "element", "day")
  id     value1 element day     value2
1  1 -0.6264538   TEST1  15 -0.8204684
2  2  0.1836433   TEST1  15  0.4874291
3  3 -0.8356286   TEST1  15  0.7383247
4  4  1.5952808   TEST1  15  0.5757814
5  5  0.3295078   TEST1  15 -0.3053884
```

It's worth pointing out the comment by thelatemail: "Joining on `id` is not the same as joining on `id/element/day`". However, in this specific example, because `element` and `day` are the same for all records in both tables we get the same result.

> Original result

Data

```
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(id = seq(1,5), value1 = rnorm(5), element = "TEST1", day = 15) 
df2 <- data.frame(id = seq(1,5), value2 = rnorm(5), element = "TEST1", day = 15) 
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "id")
```

Output:

```
  id     value1 element.x day.x     value2 element.y day.y
1  1 -0.6264538     TEST1    15 -0.8204684     TEST1    15
2  2  0.1836433     TEST1    15  0.4874291     TEST1    15
3  3 -0.8356286     TEST1    15  0.7383247     TEST1    15
4  4  1.5952808     TEST1    15  0.5757814     TEST1    15
5  5  0.3295078     TEST1    15 -0.3053884     TEST1    15
```

Comment: Wow I didn't realize it auto checks the columns.  Thanks!

Comment: @Amstell Glad I could help

Comment: Joining on `id` is not the same as joining on `id/element/day` though - see my extended answer below. One must be careful to get what is required.

Comment: @thelatemail Thank you for the comment. You're right but in this example the three columns are the same in both tables so we get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = c("id", "element", "day"))
```

Comment: That assumes that `day` and `element` are the same in both data sets.

Comment: Yes, but the question states 'the extra columns currently in my code that are the same'. If they aren't, how would one decide which of them to keep?

Comment: This works, thanks!  In my original data merge there are a lot of variables that are the same so I was hoping to not have to type them all out.

Comment: @Axeman - "same column" name doesn't necessarily mean "same column with the same data in it"

Comment: `"how would one decide which of them to keep?"` - it's a left-join, keep the left-side of the merge.

Answer (score 1):

After having checked that these columns are indeed the same, you could just remove them before doing the join

```
if (all(df1[,c('element', 'day')] == df2[,c('element', 'day')]))
  df <- left_join(df1[,setdiff(colnames(df1),c('element', 'day'))], df2, by = "id")
else
  stop("Should not happen!?")
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the easiest way to achieve what you want.

```
df <- left_join(df1, df2, by = "id", suffix = c("", ".annoying_duplicate_column")) %>%
  select(-ends_with(".annoying_duplicate_column"))
```